# Проверка ввода на наличие букв

Tags: c++, массивы, типы-данных, преобразование-типов, проверка

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    const int SIZE = 6;
    const int availableDigits[SIZE]{ 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20 };
    
    bool isThere = false;
    

    while (!isThere)
    {
        cin >> number;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (number == availableDigits[i])
            {
                isThere = true;
                cout << number << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проверка ввода пользователя

Есть диапазон допустимых значений, указанный в массиве, с числами работает нормально, но если ввести букву, то как я понял происходит неявное преобразование типов и проверка не отрабатывает

пытался прекрутить проверку isdigit но ничего путного не вышло.

подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать проверку с учётом букв и возможно ли это при хранении данных в int или нужно менять тип данных?

Comment: Проверяйте `if (cin >> number) ...` — если `false`, то вы читаете что-то не то, и далее, что бы вы ни читали, пока не сбросите флаг `fail`, у вас ничего не будет читать вообще...

Comment: @Hary, честно не понял...

Comment: При попытке считать букву в переменную типа `int` поток ввода `std::cin` переходит в ошибочное состояние. Проверка `if (cin >> number)` вернёт `false`. Чтобы восстановить поток, восстанавливаем флаги состояния [`cin.clear();`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear). Затем очищаем ошибочный ввод из входного потока [`cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), decltype(std::cin)::traits_type::to_int_type('\n'));`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).